# Lost data in Android application when

Tags: java, android

I have a problem so I do not know why how to throw an application from memory data given object is lost, but as I exit the application these data are.

this class which save data to SharedPrefernce

```
 public class MySharedPreference {

        public static final String PREFS_NAME = "LIST_CARD";
        public static final String CARD = "CARD";

        public MySharedPreference() {
            super();
        }

        public void saveCardToSharedPreference(Context context, ArrayList<Card> cardList) {

            SharedPreferences settings;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
            settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = settings.edit();
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            String jsonString = gson.toJson(cardList);
            editor.putString(CARD, jsonString);
            editor.commit();
        }

        public ArrayList getCardList(Context context) {

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
            List<Card> card;

            sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            if (sharedPreferences.contains(CARD)) {
                String jsonCard = sharedPreferences.getString(CARD, null);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Card[] cardItem = gson.fromJson(jsonCard, Card[].class);
                card = Arrays.asList(cardItem);
                card = new ArrayList(card);
            } else
                return null;
            return (ArrayList) card;
        }
    }
```

MainActivity

this class which show my list card

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ArrayList<Card> cardsList = new ArrayList<Card>();

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
    }

    private TextView textCard;
    private CardAdapter cardAdapter;
    private RecyclerView cardRecyclerView;
    private LinearLayout cardLayout;
    private MySharedPreference mySharedPreference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Typeface custom_fonts = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
        Typeface custom_fonts2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf");
        mySharedPreference = new MySharedPreference();

        cardLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutEmptyCard);
        cardLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Default app = (Default) getApplicationContext();
        cardsList = app.getListCard();

        if (cardsList.size() > 0) {
            cardsList = new ArrayList<Card>();
            cardsList = app.getListCard();
            cardLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            mySharedPreference.getCardList(MainActivity.this);
            cardRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleViewCard);
            cardAdapter = new CardAdapter(this, cardsList);
            cardRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
            cardRecyclerView.setAdapter(cardAdapter);

        }
        if (cardsList.size() == 0) {
            cardLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        TextView title_app = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        title_app.setTypeface(custom_fonts);

        textCard = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCard);
        textCard.setTypeface(custom_fonts);

        Button addCardButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addCardButton);
        addCardButton.setTypeface(custom_fonts2);
        addCardButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addCard();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.addCard) {
            addCard();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void addCard() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GetNumberActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            try {
                this.finishAffinity();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think you didn't need to post the error log?

Comment: You never call `saveCardToSharedPreference()` in the code that you've posted and you don't do anything with the return value of `mySharedPreference.getCardList(MainActivity.this);`

Comment: Titus  I call saveCardToSharedPreference() In another activity

Comment: How about the other thing ? Shouldn't you do something like this: `cardsList 
 = mySharedPreference.getCardList(MainActivity.this);` ?

Comment: I try this code but when nothing done  card not  load

Comment: I'm not sure what this does `app.getListCard()` but if it returns an empty list this `if (cardsList.size() > 0)` condition won't be `true` and the data from SharedPreference will not be loaded.